# c# replace last character in every line

Tags: c#, file

How can I replace the last character in every line?

Example:

```
rtt45|20160706|N2413847|aneess kim|20160727|
rtt45|20160706|N2247673|ram thomus|20160729|
rtt45|20160706|N2373039|rohan kumar|20160721|
```

I have tried

```
string rr = "D:\\temp\\test_07272016020733.txt";
string lines = File.ReadAllText(rr);
lines =lines.Replace("| \n", "\n");
```

Comment: Are you sure theres a space after | ?

Comment: no spaces are there i tried with lines =lines.Replace("|\n", "\n"); not working

Comment: Most likely reason for this not to work is `'\r'` character.

Comment: Sure its not "|\r\n" ? all this would be visible in your debugger

Comment: EndOfLine is CR or LF or CRLF

Comment: @bugFinder thanks  it worked  lines =lines.Replace("|\r\n", "\r\n");

Comment: @aparnachowdary - would that replace the last line's end character? Perhaps put a `.TrimEnd('|')` at the end.

Comment: @Bryan Woodford  thanks need to put .trim('|') at the end

Comment: \r\n are standard windows line ends.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
string rr = "D:\\temp\\test_07272016020733.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(rr);
lines = lines.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('|')).ToArray();
```

EDIT: If you want it all in a single string to end with:

```
var text = string.join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

For completeness, in a single line keeping variable names in tact:

```
string rr = "D:\\temp\\test_07272016020733.txt";    
string lines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines(rr).Select(x => x.TrimEnd('|')));
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
lines = lines.Replace("| \n", "\n");
```

with

```
lines = lines.Replace("|" + System.Environment.NewLine, System.Environment.NewLine);
```

or (equal)

```
lines = lines.Replace("|\r\n", "\r\n");
```